# How to set Listener On the Edit text of the Custom List view in android

Tags: android, listview

I am inflating the `ListView` By using the `BaseAdapter` and View holder. Inside the List view on each row their are 3 Text view and 1 Edit text.

Now I want to set Listener on to the List view. Means If I click any of the row Listener has to get set so that I will get the position of that row inside the List view. Listener on the text view is set by doing  `"android:focusable="false"` " But Listener on the Edit text is not getting the Set.

I have Set `Textwacher` on the Edit text It's working properly.

```
EditTextWacher editTextWacher = new EditTextWacher(viewHolder);
viewHolder.editTextQuantity.addTextChangedListener(editTextWacher);
```

I don't know exact problem why this is happening I have set focusable false Inside the Edit text. Still is not working.

**Edit** 
**[image: Adding the Screen Shot]**

Answer (score 2):

Try not to add `android:focusable="false"` to the view that you want to perform any listener on it. In this case remove the `android:focusable="false"` from the `EditText`.

Comment: When I remove android:focusable="false"  line from the Edit text Listener will get removed from the textview also. But when I put above line In the Edit Text of the XML and removed from all other widgets means from text view then that Listener will work. If I put android:focusable="false" on the Edit Text Listener working properly.